# WSO2 Enterprise Integrator Clustering

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator

When clustering WSO2 products, you create a database for the registry and other items that WSO2 product use for operations. With the combined WSO2 Enterprise Integrator, it consist of multiple elements (ESB, Business Process Manager, Message Broker, Analytics, and MSF4J).

Do you create different registry database for each sub-product or you use only one that is created for the first?

OPTION #1: WSO2_USER_DB, REGISTRY_DB, REGISTRY_LOCAL1, REGISTRY_LOCAL2

OPTION #2: ESB_WSO2_USER_DB, ESB_REGISTRY_DB, ESB_REGISTRY_LOCAL1, ESB_REGISTRY_LOCAL2, MB_WSO2_USER_DB, MB_REGISTRY_DB, MB_REGISTRY_LOCAL1, MB_REGISTRY_LOCAL2 ... etc.

I understand that user database can be shared since the authentication manager is similar. But is it the case with the registry database?
I'm new to clustering so this question might be a little not appropriate for advanced users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each of the profiles included in the EI is separate runtimes. You need to configure the profiles only according to your use case.

For example: If you are using Integrator profile (ESB) and MB profile (MB) you need to maintain two different registry data sources for ESB and MB as defined in your second option.

OPTION #2: ESB_WSO2_USER_DB, ESB_REGISTRY_DB, ESB_REGISTRY_LOCAL1, ESB_REGISTRY_LOCAL2, MB_WSO2_USER_DB, MB_REGISTRY_DB, MB_REGISTRY_LOCAL1, MB_REGISTRY_LOCAL2.

If you want to share the users across both applications, you can use one USER_DB instead of using two separate USER_DBs for ESB_WSO2_USER_DB and MB_WSO2_USER_DB.

EI clustering guide can be found from https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI610/Clustered+Deployment

Answer (score 1):

WSO2 EI can offer various services, usually separately. For example WSO2 EI for integration or WSO2 EI for process automation.

When you install this product in clustering you do it under a specific role and not combined.

In essence you have local registry for each node and one shared for the synchronization of artifacts.

I hope it helps you.

Comment: The idea of having WSO2EI is to bundle related products so they work together. Currently each sub product is using default H2 database in its repository directory